# Woocommerce get order id in order page

Tags: woocommerce

I try to get the order id in my hook woocommerce_checkout_process in order page but i've no value, these are the method i tried :

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'is_cumul');

function is_cumul() { 
     print_r(WC()->order->id);


       }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: why would you want to get the order id on process checkout when there's no order yet?  the checkout is just being processed.

Comment: i need to test a variable before validating order ...

Comment: actually i just need to check a value of my checkout add-on (plug woocommerce checkout add-on) before to validate order but i don't know how to get this value. I thought with order if, but it could be in JS also to see if radio button is checked...

Comment: So you want to validate a checkout option? That's an entirely different question. Can you update your question with what you are actually trying to do? Include all information about the additional checkout field, though I'm surprised the plugin doesn't allow you to set the extra field as required. Here's my tutorial on adding [checkout fields](https://www.kathyisawesome.com/woocommerce-customize-checkout-fields/). It may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

woocommerce_checkout_process hook is triggered before order is placed. You should use woocommerce_thankyou hook instead of it. It will give you $order_id as a function argument.

Comment: i need to test a variable before validating order

Comment: In that case, you should try accessing cart object and not order. Because order is not placed yet. Order will be placed once your validation is passed.

Comment: but can i get the order id via cart object ?

Comment: When you use this hook, you can NOT get order id. Because order will be placed once this process is complete. This hook will trigger and after it is passed, then order will be placed. NOT BEFORE THAT.

Comment: actually i just need to check a value of my checkout add-on (plug woocommerce checkout add-on) before to validate order but i don't know how to get this value. I thought with order if, but it could be in JS also to see if radio button is checked...

Comment: You can try "woocommerce_after_checkout_validation" hook. It gives you 2 parameters. second is error, you can append your error there. Argument 1 you will get while implementing hook is, the "Data". So, ideally it should work.

Comment: sorry i don't understand why is it better...? WC()->order->id will work ?

Comment: with first or second hook what i need now is to check my orde form field but i don't know how to get these fields ($_POST['my_field_name']) ??) or JS ?